# Как в EF использовать один Context в двух проектах

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Доброго времени суток коллеги. Есть ASP Core проект использующий EF для доступа к БД. Стала необходимость в создании еще одного проекта в данном решении, которое должно использовать контекст работы с БД из первого проекта, как возможно это сделать, если просто ссылку дать на контекст первого проекта - не взлетит, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Приложение как правило разделяют на слои и ваша база в идеале должна жить в отдельном проекте в виде библиотеки, а у тех, кто ей пользуется только иметься необходимые зависимые библиотеки и конфигурации.

Comment: В общем-то должно работать и так, если вы добавите проект в reference, установите все зависимые библиотеки с нужными версиями(EF в основном) и продублируете нужный конфиг. Но все же лучше перенести в отдельный проект свою БД.

Comment: @Alex Krass перенести в отдельный проект - согласен, но это дело последующего рефакторинга, сейчас из за срочности (как всегда) нужно как быстро сделать, например ссылкой. Подскажите, я делаю ссылку на основной проект, а как дальше, как мне контекст достать? Если есть какие ссылки, буду рад

Comment: Может имеются ссылки с примерами переноса в отдельный проект, буду рад любой информации

Comment: Если просто прицепить ссылку на проект, то класс контекста не находит? Может там не указана правильно доступность public для классов контекста и модели + на новый проект тоже установите EF такой же версии.

Comment: @Alex Krass, спасибо работает